# "TapkuLibrary/TapkuLibrary.h" File Not Found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, tapku

I am trying to build my app but I received an error that `"TapkuLibrary/TapkuLibrary.h" file not found` but the file is added to my references.

I am not the one who did this project, this was just past to me without proper turn over.

[image]

I actually replaced my laptop and just open my source code from a new one with XCode 7.3.1

I also tried several solutions that I found here but still not working.

I'm also loosing some Link Binaries,

[image]

Comment: Try to `clean project` or `delete the derived data`?

Comment: May be the file path changed? Readd the library.

Comment: @TonyHan I did that already, still the same.

Comment: @iphonic I changed the Header Search Paths already

Comment: Post a screenshot with more info?

Comment: Try "TapkuLibrary.h" only rather than TapkuLibrary/TapkuLibrary.h

Comment: @TonyHan I added another screenshot of some link binaries that are missing. I am not the one who did the project it was just past to me without proper turn over. I'm just trying to figure out how will I solve this problem. I hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: @gurmandeep done that. Also not working.

Comment: Then there can be a case that the reference of the file is present and the actual file does not exist.